# Standards for adding versioning to geoprocessing scripts?

Tags: arcpy, geoprocessing-service

Is there a standard way to add versioning for geoprocessing scripts and tools?

Currently, I have a folder for each geoprocessing tool which contains:

- the python script: this is the script that is run by the tool
- the toolbox: this contains the settings for parameters
- README: which has information on how to run the tool

These are geoprocessing tools that are published as a service. These aren't really python packages, and the individual scripts aren't really modules since they aren't meant to be imported.

A rudimentary way of implementing versioning would be to just manually keep track of them in the README or python script, but I want to know if there are standards or best practices or suggestions for geoprocessing script versions.

I am already using github. Ideally I am looking for a solution that allows someone to tell which version of a geoprocessing script is published as a service or deployed in some environment, something that can easily be discerned, like version 2.0.4, as opposed to a commit hash. I am deploying and patching geoprocessing services to multiple machines, so I need a way to tell if a geoprocessing service is up to date.

Comment: Best practice is called [version control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control). Keep your code and associated files in a git repository. GitHub and GitLab make this easy.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am using version control. I should have been more specific, I have added some additional comments in edits.

Comment: Tag your releases and use something like [versioneer](https://github.com/python-versioneer/python-versioneer)?